# Force a one-time no indent even after a blank line

Tags: macros, indentation

I've defined a Comment macro in the MWE below.    I want it to start a new line after the comment, without an indent.    If I were to remove the blank line after the macro, there would be no indent, but I don't always remember to do that.    Is there a way to force a once-off no indent that will override the effect of the blank line? Thanks for any recommendation.   Note that I *dont* want to force noindent globally (that's trivial), just in this particular instance.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\parindent=10 pt
\def\CommentCR#1{{\sf #1\leavevmode\newline\noindent}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\CommentCR{I want no indentation even if I leave a space after this line.}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the cuff, but I suppose there are more elegant solutions:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\parindent=10pt
\parskip=20pt

\makeatletter
\newcommand\CommentCR[1]{%
  % If you wish the comment not to form a paragraph on its own,
  % but to be part of the paragraph which LaTeX is about to create,
  % then uncomment "\ifhmode\else" and "\fi".
  %\ifhmode\else
    \par
    % If you don't wish vertical \parskip-gap to the next line,
    % uncomment "\vskip-\parskip".
    %\vskip-\parskip
    \noindent
  %\fi
  {\sffamily#1}\par
  % If you don't wish vertical \parskip-gap to the next line,
  % uncomment "\vskip-\parskip".
  %\vskip-\parskip
  \noindent
  \@ifnextchar\par{\@afterindentfalse\@afterheading\vskip-\parskip}{}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\CommentCR{I want no indentation even if I leave a space after this line.} 

\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[1]

\newpage

\lipsum[1]
\CommentCR{I want no indentation even if I leave a space after this line.}
\par\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[1]

\newpage

\lipsum[1]
\CommentCR{I want no indentation even if I leave a space after this line.}
\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @UlrichDiez and #egreg, both gave me exactly what I wanted (after uncommenting out the vskips as proposed.)       I selected the second answer because it seems a little easier to follow.

Comment: @LeoSimon Be aware that egreg's solution is much better than mine if you do not necessarily want the line to be broken after the comment. Mine has the side-effect of  actually starting a new paragraph in any case (and hiding that fact by doing negative vertical skips for undoing the vertical `\parskip`-glue) which implies the carrying out of `\everypar` in places where you probably don't want it. Also egreg's solution avoids `\@ifnextchar` which might be redefined by some package.

Comment: so far yours works fine, will upgrade to egreg's if I need to.    Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your specification is quite incomplete. Here's a set of macros that check what comes along; if it is `\par` or `<space>\par`, then `\par\noindent` is issued. Otherwise nothing gets done.

It is assumed that you don't play nasty tricks and your input is plain as you showed.

Please, note that `\sf` has been deprecated for more than 25 years.

```latex
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\parindent}{10pt}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\CommentCR[1]{%
  {\sffamily#1}\suppress@start
}
\newcommand\suppress@start{%
  \futurelet\CR@a\suppress@parindent
}
\newcommand\suppress@parindent{%
  \ifx\CR@a\par
    \let\CR@b\suppress@par
  \else
    \let\CR@b\suppress@space
  \fi
  \CR@b
}
\newcommand{\suppress@par}[1]{\par\noindent}
\newcommand{\suppress@space}{%
  \ifx\CR@a\@sptoken
    \long\def\CR@c##1{\space\suppress@start##1}%
  \else
    \let\CR@c\relax
  \fi
  \CR@c
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-3]
\CommentCR{I want no indentation even if I leave a space after this line.}%

\lipsum[1][1-3]

\lipsum[1][1-3]
\CommentCR{I want no indentation even if I leave a space after this line.}

\lipsum[1][1-3]

\lipsum[1][1-3]
\CommentCR{I want no indentation even if I leave a space after this line.}
\lipsum[1][1-3]

\lipsum[1][1-3]
\CommentCR{I want no indentation even if I leave a space after this line.}xyz
\lipsum[1][1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want is this

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\parindent=10 pt
\def\CommentCR#1{{\sf #1\leavevmode\\\mbox{}\\}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\CommentCR{I want no indentation even if I leave a space after this line.}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: this wouldn't work at all if in the case asked for where there us a blank line after teh comment macro